# Applying for a visa for Pakistan as a student in Australia

Tags: visas, australia, pakistan, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan studying in a university in Australia, and am currently in Australia (Please note that I do not have a permanent residence in Australia, only a study visa).

I want to travel to my friend in Pakistan for a week or two. Am I able to apply for a Pakistan Visit or Tourism Visa from Australia, while holding a Sri Lankan passport?

Comment: did you ask the embassy of Pakistan in Australia?

Comment: I did send them an email 2 weeks back, I didnt get a reply still

Comment: Based on your temporary resident status in Australia, you can either apply for the visa from within Australia or in Sri Lanka

Comment: @karancan , how did you find this out ? Have you tried what im doing too? :)

Comment: @karancan can you perhaps add an answer?

Comment: Based on my past experiences in an analogous situation, you can apply for a visa for a 3rd country as long as you are not in a place where you are considered a tourist. In this case, you are not a tourist in Australia which means you can apply for a third country visa while in Australia

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are residing legally in the country you can apply for a visa to Pakistan:

> Applicants holding passports other than Australia/ Fiji Passport
>   should provide proof of their residential status in Australia/Fiji.
>   Their passports must contain the appropriate entry. All others should
>   apply for visa in their country of origin.

*From the [Pakistan Embassy in Australia website](http://www.pakistan.org.au/visas.php)*

You will need to show proof of travel, funds and your friend's details. In addition a letter from your friend addresses to the embassy and a copy of his/her NIC (national identity card) should also help.